# Setting Azure App Service server stack on a Bicep template

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy a .NET Core 3.1 Azure App Service on Linux using a Bicep template from Azure CLI. The app service and corresponding app service plan are deployed correctly but the app service stack settings are empty on the Azure portal and I have to set these manually. I tried setting the metadata property on the 'Microsoft.Web/sites' resource and also on the 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' resource, but the result was the same.

This is my app service plan:

```
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'MyAppService'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'P1v2'
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}
```

Here is my first attempt to set the stack using 'Microsoft.Web/sites' as suggested here:

https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/3314

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'MyApp'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'dotnet|3.1'
      appCommandLine: 'dotnet MyApp.dll'
      metadata: [
        {
          name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
          value: 'dotnetcore'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my second attempt to set the stack using 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' as suggested here:

[Bicep - How to config Runtime Stack to Azure App Service (Bicep version 0.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823980/bicep-how-to-config-runtime-stack-to-azure-app-service-bicep-version-0-4)

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'MyApp'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'dotnet|3.1'
      appCommandLine: 'dotnet MyApp.dll'
    }
  }
  resource webConfig 'config' = {
    name: 'web'
    properties: {
      metadata: [
        {
          name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
          value: 'dotnetcore'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result is the same. The deployment is completed with the following warning:

> Warning BCP037: The property "metadata" is not allowed on objects of
> type "SiteConfig". Permissible properties include
> "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds", "acrUserManagedIdentityID", "alwaysOn",
> "apiDefinition", "apiManagementConfig", "autoHealEnabled",
> "autoHealRules", "autoSwapSlotName", "azureStorageAccounts",
> "connectionStrings", "cors", "defaultDocuments",
> "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled", "documentRoot", "experiments",
> "ftpsState", "functionAppScaleLimit",
> "functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled", "handlerMappings",
> "healthCheckPath", "http20Enabled", "httpLoggingEnabled",
> "ipSecurityRestrictions", "javaContainer", "javaContainerVersion",
> "javaVersion", "keyVaultReferenceIdentity", "limits", "loadBalancing",
> "localMySqlEnabled", "logsDirectorySizeLimit", "managedPipelineMode",
> "managedServiceIdentityId", "minimumElasticInstanceCount",
> "minTlsVersion", "netFrameworkVersion", "nodeVersion",
> "numberOfWorkers", "phpVersion", "powerShellVersion",
> "preWarmedInstanceCount", "publicNetworkAccess", "publishingUsername",
> "push", "pythonVersion", "remoteDebuggingEnabled",
> "remoteDebuggingVersion", "requestTracingEnabled",
> "requestTracingExpirationTime", "scmIpSecurityRestrictions",
> "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain", "scmMinTlsVersion", "scmType",
> "tracingOptions", "use32BitWorkerProcess", "virtualApplications",
> "vnetName", "vnetPrivatePortsCount", "vnetRouteAllEnabled",
> "websiteTimeZone", "webSocketsEnabled", "windowsFxVersion",
> "xManagedServiceIdentityId". If this is an inaccuracy in the
> documentation, please report it to the Bicep Team.
> [https://aka.ms/bicep-type-issues]

The resources are deployed, but the app service stack setting is blank and I have to set it manually to make it work.

[image: App service stack settings]

I know that in the ARM template this is set on the CURRENT_STACK property of the Microsoft.Web/sites/config metadata (as suggested here https://cloudstep.io/2020/11/18/undocumented-arm-oddities-net-core-app-services/). However, this doesn't seem to be supported (yet) in Bicep. If anyone has found a working solution, please post it here.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello @erionpc, as you can see under [siteconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?tabs=bicep#siteconfig) in the Microsoft documentation there isn't metadata parameter any more .

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT but it still works, and is currently the only way to declare a dotnet core stack for Windows app plans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Metadata parameter is not available anymore in the **[`SiteConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?tabs=bicep#siteconfig)**. The stack setting can be mentioned `LinuxFxVersion`.

So, solution will be Instead of using `dotnet|3.1` , You should use `DOTNETCORE|3.1`.The over all code will be as below:

```
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'MyAppService'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'P1v2'
  }
  kind: 'linux'
}
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'anumantestapp'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|3.1'
      appCommandLine: 'dotnet MyApp.dll'
    }
  }
}
```

**Ouptut:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be of help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's  better to use the sites/config to set up the .NET version

```
resource appServiceConfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'web'
  parent: appService
  properties: {
    netFrameworkVersion: 'v7.0'
    use32BitWorkerProcess: false
    http20Enabled: true
    ftpsState: 'Disabled'
    alwaysOn: true
    metadata: [
      {
        name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
        value: 'dotnet'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is it better? Can you explain for readers?