# Azure Bicep Deployment - Some configurations wont come up on UI

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I tried to deploy an app service using bicep template. some configurations like netFrameworkVersion doesn't show on the UI.
the value I passed in the bicep is

```
siteConfig:{
  netFrameworkVersion:'v6.0'
}
```

[image: uiview]

I am not sure what I am doing anything wrong here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bicep - How to config Runtime Stack to Azure App Service (Bicep version 0.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823980/bicep-how-to-config-runtime-stack-to-azure-app-service-bicep-version-0-4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the current stack as well:

```bicep
siteConfig = {
  netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
  metadata: [
    {
      name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
      value: 'dotnet'
    }
  ]
}
```