# AzureRm 3.33.0 version create app service conditionally on basis of input var?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

Have developed a common module to create azure app service plan and app service for projects. In **azurerm version 2** setting kind variable in app service plan resource with value linux or windows.

But with **azurerm 3 upgrade** there is one app service plan resource and 2 app services resources. **Is there anyway to decide which resource be created depending on value of input variable apart from using count like below** . Script Used
`resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app_service_plan" {`

`name                = local.name`

`location            = var.location`

`resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name`

`tags                = var.tags`

`os_type             = var.os_type}`

for windows

`resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "app_service" {`

`name                    = local.name`

`location                = var.location`

`resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name`

`service_plan_id         = var.app_service_plan_id`

`count                   = var.kind == "Windows" ?1:0}`

for linux

`resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app_service" {`

`name                    = local.name`

`location                = var.location`

`resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name`

`service_plan_id         = var.app_service_plan_id`

`count                   = var.kind == "Linux" ?1:0}`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there any way to decide which resource be created depending on value of input variable apart from using count**

Yes, there is another way to create a web app (resource) depends on the value of input variable (var:kind).

Using `depends_on` block:

```bash
depends_on = [var.kind == "windows" ? azurerm_windows_web_app : azurerm_linux_web_app]
```

Or you can also use  [terraform modules](https://registry.terraform.io/browse/modules).

*Reference:* Sample terraform web app deployment [module "app service"](https://github.com/kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-app-service) if required.

&

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963001/how-to-deploy-windows-azure-app-service-with-net-stack-using-bicep/74990645#74990645) worked by me in bicep for other approach.

Comment: Dont think this will work. Can you share the sample script ?