# Deploying an Azure Web App via Bicep does not set Stack

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, .net-7.0

I am creating an Azure Web App via Bicep to host an ASP.NET Core 7.0 Website. My Bicep contains:

```
    netFrameworkVersion:  'v7.0'
    requestTracingEnabled: true
    remoteDebuggingEnabled: true
    remoteDebuggingVersion: 'VS2022'
    httpLoggingEnabled: true
    use32BitWorkerProcess: false
    ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
    managedPipelineMode: 'Integrated'
```

But when I deploy the Bicep it is not being set to .NET 7 and the settings look like below:

[image]

I found some posts on SO that suggests some solution for metadata but I am not sure how and if this solution apply to .NET 7.

**Are you aware of any missing setting that I need to add to have this set to the picture below:**

[image]

Comment: are you using windows or linux app service plan ? the solution using specific metadatas should work for net7 as well, give it a try tbh.

Comment: Windows. I have added this:
resource website_config_metadata 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'metadata'
  parent: website
  properties: {
    CURRENT_STACK : 'dotnet'
  }
}
And it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy Linux web app, use linuxFxVersion parameter:

```
linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|7.0'
```

For windows deployment, use the following parameters:

```
metadata :[
        {
          name:'CURRENT_STACK'
          value:'dotnet'
        }
      ]
netFrameworkVersion:'v7.0'
```

Full bicep available in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963001/how-to-deploy-windows-azure-app-service-with-net-stack-using-bicep)